# Different Builds for Simulator and iPhone

Tags: objective-c, build-process

The app that I'm working on has a URL that it accesses for data, this URL is defined as a constant as follows:

```
#define kURLToSendRequestsTo @"http://www.localhost.com/dataAccess.php"
```

However, this URL will only work for the simulator. For the iPhone I have to change the URL to a test site manually.

What I need is a way to change it dynamically so I don't have to manually change it each time. Something like this:

```
#if iPhone

#define kURLToSendRequestsTo @"http://www.localhost.com/dataAccess.php"

#elseif simulator

#define kURLToSendRequestsTo @"http://www.testsite.com/dataAccess.php"

#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constants you want are:

```
TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
```

and:

```
TARGET_OS_IPHONE
```

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/15-Configuring_Applications/configuring_applications.html).